# jQuery combine 2 vars into 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Is there a way to combine 2 vars into 1?

I need to reset an input value each time a "Redeem Voucher button" is pressed

I have the following vars:

```
var buttonColor = $(this).attr('class');

var goldOriginalTotal = '$3916.64';
var silverOriginalTotal = '$1396.64';
var bronzeOriginalTotal = '$724.64';
```

`buttonColor` will give me gold, silver or bronze. I want to use this to call either goldOriginalTotal, silverOriginalTotal or bronzeOriginalTotal.

I'd like to use it as below but I don't think it's possible :(

```
$(this).find('input.' + buttonColor).text(buttonColor + OriginalTotal);
```

eg `buttonColor + OriginalTotal` should equal `goldOriginalTotal` which should print out `$3916.64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it would be better to have the three variables you have now as properties of an object which is keyed by the expected class name. Try this:

```
var buttonColor = $(this).attr('class');
var originalTotal = {
    gold: '$3916.64',
    silver: '$1396.64',
    bronze: '$724.64'
};
$(this).find('input.' + buttonColor).text(originalTotal[buttonColor]);
```

What you are currently attempting to do, `buttonColor + OriginalTotal` is resulting in string concatenation. You could use `eval` to programmatically access a variable by name, but it is considered horrific practice to do this. The above solution is the preferred method.

Comment: Yeah thanks mate I suspected what I was trying to do was pretty appalling. Thanks for showing me a better way.

Comment: @twernt You were close though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your values to get an object member instead.

```
var buttonColor = $(this).attr('class');

var originalTotals = {
  gold: '$3916.64',
  silver: '$1396.64',
  bronze: '$724.64',
}

$(this).find('input.' + buttonColor).text(originalTotals[buttonColor]);
```